# Is there a WordPress widget for my webpage?

Tags: widgets

I'd like to show a summary of my recent posts on my homepage. (Like the headlines and perhaps a few lines of text.) My site is *not* running on WordPress.

Is there a code snippet for that?

**Edit:**

When  I said "widget", I didn't mean it in the WordPress sense. I meant a code snippet.

Comment: It doesn't get any better than http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/03/15/query-posts-widget-wordpress-plugin

Comment: useful guide: http://www.corvidworks.com/articles/wordpress-content-on-other-pages

Answer (score 2):

For a non-WP site, [Developer's Guide - Google AJAX Feed API - Google Code](http://code.google.com/apis/feed/) is easy to use.

Comment: Um? Broken link.

Comment: Didn't realize that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a default widget that ships with WordPress called "Recent Posts."  It displays a list of titles of your recent posts.

There are also several other similar widgets with different features, some of which might allow for a few lines of text.  Try searching the Plug-in Repository for "[recent posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=recent+posts&sort=)."

Comment: How can I include this in my (non-wordpress) pages?

Comment: Short answer: you can't.  WordPress widgets are built to be displayed in the WordPress sidebar.  If you want to display a list of recent posts on a non-WordPress site, I suggest using RSS.

Comment: Long answer: (assuming site does use PHP) you will need to load WP core and call separately instanced copy of widget (or mess with creating whole separate sidebar for it). In this specific scenario you are indeed better using RSS as source and whatever way to display it that non-WP site has available.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to publish a headline and excerpt of your latest posts on a non-WordPress, I'd use FeedBurner's [BuzzBoost](http://www.google.com/support/feedburner/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78976) feature, it has always done the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following snippet in you non-WP page:

```
// This is so that we can use WP functions
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Now you can call [wp_get_recent_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) to get the latests posts.

But reading your question agin, it seems that you are NOT using Wordpress, but you want a function similar to wordpress? In that case, you're in the wrong forum. You should ask it over at StackExchange.

And if you are not using WP, then you need to fill in more details. Are you using any CMS? IS you site custom PHP? Storing data in DB? And so on.